# How do I get the name of a file's owner in Java on OSX?

Tags: java, macos

I just need to know the owner's name of a file on Mac using Java -- how can I go about getting it? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one is nasty. There is *no* standard method for getting the owner of a file (at least up to and including Java 6, which is the current production version for OSX). The easiest way right now is to use a `ProcessBuilder` to exec a call to `stat` with the name of the file as its argument, and then parse the result that will be returned on the standard output channel from the subprocess. Care must be taken when parsing the result because usernames on OSX might have spaces in.

Alternatively, use JNI.

Answer (score 16):

That't not possible until [Java 7](http://jdk7.java.net/). With Java 7, you could use [`Files#getOwner()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#getOwner%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.LinkOption...%29) for this.

```
Path          path     = Paths.get("/path/to/file.ext");
UserPrincipal owner    = Files.getOwner(path);
String        username = owner.getName();
```

Prior to Java 7, your best bet is running a command or JNI in combination with some platform native code.

**See also:**

- [Java 7 NIO Tutorial - Managing Metadata](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileAttr.html)