# Get file/directory owner's name in Java

Tags: java, io

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get the name of a file's owner in Java on OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096805/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-a-files-owner-in-java)

Is there any method on a class from java.io, java.nio, commons-io, etc. that I can use to get the owner of a given file in my filesystem?

I really don't want to create a shell to execute an unix-only/windows-only command to get it. It would look awful and wouldn't be platform independent.

Comment: @Chris: But that question was specifically about Mac OS X, and the accepted answer was tailored to that OS. This question is specifically looking for a way that is *not* the way described in that accepted answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Judging from [the Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#getOwner%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.LinkOption...%29), you should be able to do this:

```
java.nio.file.Files.getOwner(file.toPath())
```

(where `file` is an instance of `java.io.File`). Note that this requires Java 7. Also note that it will throw an `UnsupportedOperationException` on some platforms, because some file-systems, such as FAT32, have no concept of a file "owner".