# Error trying to get owner of file using UserPrincipal

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am doing the following:

[How do I get the name of a file's owner in Java on OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096805/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-a-files-owner-in-java)

Here is my code:

```
private String getOwner(File f)
{
    Path p = Paths.get(f.getAbsolutePath());
    UserPrincipal owner = Files.getOwner(p);
    return owner.getName();
}
```

I get a "cannot find symbol" error. Here it is:

```
...$ javac Delete.java
Delete.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
    UserPrincipal owner = Files.getOwner(p);
    ^
  symbol:   class UserPrincipal
  location: class Delete
1 error
```

I know what the error means and I have tried several import statements:

java.security.*; (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/)

java.nio.file.attribute; (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/)

I feel ridiculous even having to ask this but I have no idea what I could be doing wrong!

Comment: Are you sure you have `java 7` ?

Comment: I am pretty sure this means I have Java 7...      
  
javac -version / javac 1.7.0_06

Comment: Show us the exact and complete error message you get.

Comment: what happens when you `import java.nio.file.attribute.UserPrincipal`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to compile and run your code on my Mac with the following imports:

```
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.attribute.UserPrincipal;
```

and in the following format:

```
private String getOwner(File f) throws IOException {
    Path p = Paths.get(f.getAbsolutePath());
    UserPrincipal owner = Files.getOwner(p);
    return owner.getName();
}
```

You should check if you really use Java 7 in that place where you compile your code.

Comment: Ahh, ok. I will try those. I ran the javac -version in the same window in Terminal that I use to compile so I assume that's the same place!